# Yii, already define index but `Undefined Index`

Tags: post, indexing, yii, undefined

I have already properly defined the index to be `POST`-ed but still it says `Undefined Index`

Below is my code:

in the _form.php:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'clientPackagedService_id'); ?>
<?php $client = Client::model()->findByPk(1);?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'clientPackagedService_id', CHtml::listData($client->clientPackagedservices(array('condition'=>'client_id='.$client->id.' AND booking_id IS NULL')),'id','packagedServiceInfo'),
    array(              
            'disabled'=>'disabled', 
            'prompt'=>'Select Packaged Service...',
            'ajax' => array( 'type'=>'POST', //request type 
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('updateMasseuseAndStationListPSID'), //url to call.
//This line->           'data'=>array('clientPackagedService_id'=>'js:this.value', 'dt'=>'js:$("#Booking_date").val()', 'timeStart'=>'js:$("#Booking_timeStart").val()'),
                'dataType'=>'json', 
                'success'=>'js:function(data) {
                    //alert(data.masseuse);
                    var mass="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'masseuse_id').'"; 
                    $(mass).html(data.masseuse); 
                    $(mass).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                    $(mass+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                    $(mass+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px");                              

                    var station="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'station_id').'"; 
                    $(station).html(data.station); 
                    $(station).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                    $(station+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                    $(station+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px"); 

                    //alert(data.timeEnd);
                    var timeEnd="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'timeEnd').'";
                    $(timeEnd).val(data.timeEnd);                           

                }',                         
            ) 
        )
    ); ?>
```

in the controller.php:

```
public function actionUpdateMasseuseAndStationListPSID(){       

    $sid = Booking::getServices($_POST['clientPackagedService_id']);

    ....(codes to update Masseuse, Station, and TimeEnd.
}
```

in the model.php

```
public static function getServices($cpsID){

    $psID = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT packagedService_id FROM client_packagedservice WHERE id='.$cpsID)->queryAll();
    $sID = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT service_id FROM packaged_service WHERE id = '.$psID)->queryAll();

    return $sID;

}
```

As you can see, I have already posted the appropriate name `$_POST['clientPackagedService_id']` in the controller.php, but I still get the `Error 500: Undefined index: clientPackagedService_id`.

Did I do something wrong somewhere? Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is the data your are posting with ajax request. This is your data:

```
'data'=>array('clientPackagedService_id'=>'js:this.value', 'dt'=>'js:$("#Booking_date").val()', 'timeStart'=>'js:$("#Booking_timeStart").val()'),
```

Try to change it into this:

```
'data'=>array('clientPackagedService_id'=>'js:$(this).value', 'dt'=>'js:$("#Booking_date").val()', 'timeStart'=>'js:$("#Booking_timeStart").val()'),
```

Best way for debugging ajax request is to inspect browser's console. You can see ajax's posted data and realize your problem.

Comment: After changing, I'm still having the same problem. 
`...index.php?r=booking/updateMasseuseAndStationListPSID` 500 (Internal Server Error). Basically when I click into that error link, it says `Undefined Index: clientPackagedService_id`